# Filter mapping issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I am using a some filter mapping for my project . The following filter pattens hit the filter

```
<filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>wygUserCheckFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>wygUserCheckFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/myProject/MyDisplay.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But the one below doesn't hit the filter

```
<filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>wygUserCheckFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/myProject/*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Why is this so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because * in the middle of the pattern matches only to the * character. Only matching url for /myProject/*.jsp-pattern is exactly same string. * does have special meaning only in the following cases (Servlet 2.4 Specification):

> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’
>     suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’
>     preﬁx is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the
>     ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In
>     this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the con- text path
>     and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact
>     matches only.

Answer (score 2):

From Servlet 2.5 spec:

> **SRV.11.2**
>
> *Specification of Mappings*
>
> In the Web application deployment
> descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix    is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is    used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’    character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this    case the servlet path
>   is the request URI minus the context path and    the path info is
>   null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.